# Pluralizations and Singularizations (Inflections) for "Media/Medium" in Rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with **Rails 5** an I just have created a `Media` model using scaffold tool.

```
rails g scaffold media name:string
```

And I got different names and routes and view etc...

[image]

It was not right pluralising, so when I `rake routes` I got `medium` unexpected routes and because of that I got different problems in the views.

[image]

When I try to use `<%= form_for @media do ..` I got complain about `no method media_index_path`.

How can I get it fixed and working well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching all day about this and being a little bit more curious when I run the very first scaffold it recommended to use something called `inflections` which basically is in charge of the pluralising and singularising words for class names:

[image]

What I did to get it fixed was to use `inflections` in the next way:

1. Delete the model I just have created.

   ```
   rails d scaffold Media
   ```
2. Edit `config/initializers/inflections.rb` with:

   ```
   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
       # Here you can put the singular and plural form you expect
       inflect.irregular 'media', 'medias'
   end
   ```
3. Now execute the scaffold again:

   ```
   rails g scaffold Media
   ```

Now you must have everything in the way you expected. Because you have overwritten the ***Pluralizations*** and ***Singularizations*** ***(Inflections)*** in Ruby on Rails.

I hope it could be useful.

Answer (score 6):

This question really is a challenge to my English :D

I googled the noun *media*, and it says that some purists insist that the word *media*, which is borrowed from Latin, is the plural form of *medium*, so from this point of view, Rails generator did the right job.

But in daily English, people simply use *media* as an uncountable noun or a collective noun. If you agree on that, then adjust the **config/initializers/inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( media )
end
```